# tkinter button command not responding

Tags: python, tkinter

i am making a spambot to annoy my friends on discord and one of the functions i want is an autoclicker. i have made autoclickers before but never with buttons and UI. when i press the button the function does not work. can someone please help me?

this is the code:

````
import pyautogui 
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()

def clicker():
    global click_var 
    global click_text_var
    click_var = 0   
    #if click_var = 0: clicker is off
    #if click_var = 1: clicker is on
    if click_var == 0:
        click_var =+ 1
        click_text_var = 'stop' 

    elif click_var == 1:
        click_text_var = "start"
        click_var =- 1
    
    else:
        print('error1: clickvar not 0/1')

click_text_var = 'start'
click_var = 1
name=Label(window, text="spammer 3000", fg='black', font=("Helvetica", 30))
name.place(x=10, y=10)


clickerbtn=Button(window, text=click_text_var + " clicker", bg='grey', command=clicker)
clickerbtn.place(x=10, y=100)

window.title('the spammer 3000')
window.geometry("600x400+10+20")

window.mainloop()
clickerbtn.pack()
if click_var == 1:
    print('l')
if click_var == 0:
    something =+ 1
    print('o')
if click_var < 0:
    print('error1: clickvar not 0/1')
if click_var > 1:
    print('error1: clickvar not 0/1')```
````

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are defining `click_var = 0`.
It should work if you remove that. Also, you have written `=+` instead of `+=`. You should probably fix that also